# uninitialized constant Yajl with yajl-ruby included in Gemfile Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yajl

When I call **Yajl::Parse** in controller, i got the error "**uninitialized constant Yajl**".
I have included **gem 'yajl-ruby', '~> 1.1.0', require: 'yajl'** in Gemfile and executed "**bundle install**", but it didn't solve the problem.

I also tried to **require 'yajl'** in my controller.rb. That gives '**cannot load such file -- yajl'**.

Is there anything that i have missed?

Comment: Did you restart the Rails server?

Comment: I did, but it doesnt help.